# showing hidden div with jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, fadein, slidedown

I want to display a div content with jquery if a button is pressed. For example,

```
<button id="b1">Show text</button>
```

if the button is pressed then show this text div.

```
<div id="text">hello world.</div>
```

I've tried to use the jquery functions "fadein", "toggle", "slidedown".. however I have a problem that by default it shows the div content. I want that by default it hides the content, and shows only if the button is clicked. How I can do this? I'll highly appreciate your help with some basic example if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a css rule for that `div`:

```
div#text {
   display: none;
}
```

This will ensure that the element is hidden from the start.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/GkFu4/5/

Answer (score 3):

Set the div's display style attribute to 'none', either inline, or using a CSS class.

```
<!-- inline -->
<div id="text" style="display:none">hello world.</div>


// css class
#text { display: none; }
```

Comment: Your CSS is using an `id` selector, not a class selector.

Comment: @Jacob - My intention was to have two examples of how to make something invisible. The first using the inline `style="display:none` and the second using a CSS class. I think my answer was not clear enough to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use toggle, see the jQuery api. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
Or another example. http://jsbin.com/obumi3/